# Will adding variables which have little to no significance, affect the effect of more significant variables on the machine learning prediction?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, scikit-learn

For example:

Suppose I am trying to predict the "HEIGHT" of a giraffe.

If I have one highly correlated X variable, "AGE", and another X variable, "NUMBEROFSPOTS", which has little to no correlation with "HEIGHT", does the fact of including "NUMBEROFSPOTS" affect the effect that "AGE" has on the prediction?

And in addition, what if there were many such additional variables with little to no correlation to "HEIGHT", such as "EYECOLOUR" or "VOTINGINTENTION"?

My assumption, from some fairly limited experience using non-ML based versions of linear regression,
is that additional variables with no correlation should have no affect on the effect of "AGE" on the prediction, but that variables with low correlation may have some limited effect.
I also assume that including a lot of variables that have a low correlation would have a greater affect on the effect of "AGE" on the prediction.

Using Sklearn.logisticRegression.

P.S. I am assuming that number of spots, or the eye color, or the voting intention of the giraffe has little to no correlation with its height. I'm happy to be proven wrong. :)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "effect on the prediction." Adding variables to most models cannot possibly hurt their goodness of fit, but it usually creates overfitting as evidenced by a deterioration of out-of-sample performance.  This is an extensive subject that cannot be adequately addressed in one thread, so please search our site using keywords such as "model" and "variable selection." Other good keywords include "Lasso," "regularization," and "overfitting."

Comment: Thanks @whuber.
By "effect on the prediction" I meant the effect on the accuracy of the prediction, specifically in terms of the AUC, and/or the true positive rate.
But yes, it is an extensive subject....I will keep reading, thank you.